# How long can I stay in Jamaica without obtaining a visa and do I need to buy a round trip flight?

Tags: visas, air-travel, customs-and-immigration, us-citizens, jamaica

I am a U.S citizen looking for an adventure and have decided to take my talents to Jamaica.

I understand there is a 90-day rule where no visa is required, and that you can go to immigration to extend for another 90 days, which is what I would hope to do as my goal is to me immerse myself in Jamaican culture for about 6 months.

However, the additional 90 day extension is not guaranteed.

Do I need to purchase a round-trip flight to show proof that I plan to leave in 6 months or can I purchase a one-way ticket and purchase a flight home when I decide to do so?

Comment: When you say "take my talents", are you intending to work? Visa-free entry is usually for tourist or business visits only, not for employment.

Comment: @DavidRicherby "Adventure.... take my talents".. for me it did not sound like a work intention, it's basically the adventure of traveling.

Answer (score 3):

The [Consulate General of Jamaica](http://www.congenjamaica-ny.org/visas/requirements-2/) says you'll need a return ticket and how long you might stay is determined at entry:

> **Requirements For Entry Into Jamaica**
>
> All visitors are required to be in possession of a national passport or other acceptable travel document establishing nationality and identity, and bearing a photograph.  The  passport or other travel document must be valid for the period of intended stay in the island. Visitors are also required to show evidence of sufficient funds to support themselves during their stay and be in possession of a return or round trip ticket to another country to which they are admissible.
>
> Nationals of certain countries require, in addition to travel documents, an entry visa.  This is normally issued, on application, by a Jamaican  Consular office.
>
> The decision in respect of admission and length of stay in the country rests with the Immigration Officer at the port of entry in Jamaica.  This applies whether or not a visa is a prerequisite for entry.